# How to connect two machines using the Messenger example?

Tags: c++, opendds

I have been trying to connect two machines: both Virtual Machines, one is Xubuntu and the other is Ubuntu. I'm also very new to OpenDDS, but the best way -or so it seems- to do it is to use the .ini files. 
However, when I try to connect, I seem to fail in changing the Discovery Server, since the default is localhost:12345. Can somebody help me with that so I can configure the file properly?

I have tried using the dds_udp_conf.ini and the tcp one, but it doesn't seem to work. 
Also, I tried using unicast, but failed.

the ini file:

[common]

DCPSDebugLevel=0

DCPSInfoRepo=corbaloc::localhost::12345/DCPSInfoRepo

DCPSGlobalTransportConfig=config1

[config/config1]

transports=udp1

[transport/udp1]

transport_type=udp

And I use the syntax:
./publisher -DCPSConfigFile conf.ini

Well, the publisher and subscriber are supposed to connect, but the publisher sends some error messages and in the other VM nothing happens.
I seem to fail because I cant change the configuration in the localhost for discovery. 
When I try to run the server with a different parameter than localhost:12345 it always sends error messages too.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me where you're running the InfoRepo if both the publisher and subscriber are told the InfoRepo is running at localhost. Regardless I would recommend using the RTPS discovery and transport instead. It's easy to set up because the participants can find each other through the network's multicast without InfoRepo. This config is the simplest way to use RTPS with OpenDDS:

```
[common]
DCPSDefaultDiscovery=DEFAULT_RTPS
DCPSGlobalTransportConfig=$file

[transport/the_rtps_transport]
transport_type=rtps_udp
```

Just give this to both the programs and they should find each other. If not that would mean there's probably something's wrong with how the networking is set up on your VMs.

Comment: Hi! As you said, using InfoRepo was pretty unclear, so I tried using RTPS Discovery and it worked! Thanks for the help!